# Character string to int-atoi()

Tags: c++11

"I am trying to write code for atoi function.MY problem is actual output is not matching with the

expected output for the following case.

Input="7 U 0 T7165 0128862 089 39 5"

Actual output=2147483647

Expected output=7

The following is the link to know problem constraints
https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/atoi/"

/function to convert string to int

```
int atoi(const string A) {
    //string to store numeric in string A
    string a;

    //b and d store INT_MAX and INT_MIN in string form
    string b=to_string(INT_MAX),d=to_string(INT_MIN);

    //loop to store numeric in a
   for(int i=0;i<A.length();i++){
       if(a.length()==0&&A[i]=='-')a.push_back(A[i]);

       if(A[i]==' ')break;

       if(isdigit(A[i]))a.push_back(A[i]);
    }

    //conditions to return int
    if(a.length()==0)return 0;
    else if(a>b)return INT_MAX;
    else if(a<d)return INT_MIN;
    else{      
        int f=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
            f=f*10+(a[i]-'0');
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Time to learn how to to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: when i checked by debugging a is assigned as output.I didnt understand why? But before conditions to return int a is 7.

Comment: String comparisons of numbers won't work as you expect.